# Can't remove TeXinfo

Tags: uninstall, 21.10

One day i saw "TeXinfo" app in my activities menu. I don't know what is this app and how it got installed on my PC. I tried to uninstall it but it won't. It says that package not installed. What can i do?
Ubuntu 21.10

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open terminal and type to remove the [info](https://codesearch.debian.net/search?q=Name%3DTeXInfo&literal=1) [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/info):

```
sudo apt-get purge info
```